# executing python variable in function

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a variable called `id_choice` after it was called in a function I defined called `movie_choice`.

This is how the function looks like:

```
def movie_choice():  
    user_input = raw_input("Would you like to serch your movie by IMDB ID or by\ title? ").upper()
if user_input == "ID":
    id_choice = raw_input("Enter imdb ID: ")
    print("Serching . . .")
    return id_choice
elif user_input == "TITLE":
    title = raw_input("Enter movie title: ")
    print("Serching . . .")
    return title
elif user_input == "EXIT":
    sys.exit
else:
    print("Please enter a valid choice. ")
    return movie_choice()

api_key = '1234'
url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?%s&%s" % (id_choice, api_key)
print (url)
```

After I defined this function, for example if I'll try to `print (id_choice)` I will get an error because `id_choice` is not defined. How can I solve this problem?

I'm new to coding so I'm sorry if the answer to my question will be obvious to some of you. 
Thanks and appreciate the help!

Comment: Where are you trying to print `id_choice`? In the code above? Regardless, it would be a good idea to test whether the user has entered something at the prompt -- e.g. is the length of `id_choice` more than zero?

Comment: As a side note:`sys.exit`, like all functions, doesn't do anything unless you _call_ it, like `sys.exit()`. Also, to loop forever until you return/exit, just use a `while True:` loop around the function, don't recursively call the function from itself.

Comment: Please make it clear where you are trying to print (id_choice)

Comment: With your code as-is, what happens if the user inputs a movie title?

Comment: I didn’t get to see yet what happened if the input is title because I’m trying to get the ID working first. Currently, when I’m trying to print the URL it just printing it and ignoring the user input for id_choice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call 'id_choice' on the outside of your function,

> You need to define it ... on the **OUTSIDE** of your function

This concept is known as **scope**. Read up on it. Since the variable, 'id_choice', is defined within the 'movie_choice' function, you can only access it within that function. In the code below, I've defined it before the 'movie_choice' function. Your code should work now.

Also make sure you are **indenting** correctly. Those if statements should be indented to the **inside** of your function:

```
id_choice = ''

def movie_choice(): 
    title = '' 
    user_input = raw_input("Would you like to serch your movie by IMDB ID or by\ title? ").upper()

    if user_input == "ID":
        id_choice = raw_input("Enter imdb ID: ")
        print("Serching . . .")
        return id_choice
    elif user_input == "TITLE":
        title = raw_input("Enter movie title: ")
        print("Serching . . .")
        return title
    elif user_input == "EXIT":
        sys.exit
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid choice. ")
        return movie_choice()

api_key = '1234'
url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?%s&%s" % (id_choice, api_key)
print (url)
```

Additionally,
you need to define your other variables **OUTSIDE** your if statements.

If there's a possibility that id_choice is never going to be defined, then you cannot possibly try to print a variable that is not defined. But by defining it on the outside of your conditionals (or function), you are ensuring that those variables will always have a default value.

At the moment, your url has the chance of being incorrect because what if the user does not enter "ID" as the user input? Think of restructuring your code paths to meet that case.

In conclusion, read up on **scope** and **identation**.

Comment: My variable is changing depends on the user keyboard input which is in a part of a function with if statements

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand what you are saying. I'll update my answer to make it more clear

Comment: url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?%s&%s" % (id_choice, api_key)
print (url)
This is where i'm trying to print it out. I'm trying that the user input will change the URL line.

Comment: @dor_sam How can I possibly understand where this line is from? Please edit your answer and make it clear where the above line is located ... Outside the function? Inside?

Comment: I've just edited the code in my first comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dor_sam I've updated my answer. Again, try to use the amazing resource known as the internet to learn about scope and indentation when it comes to python...

Answer (score 0):

kay is right about needing to assign variables in the scope where you are accessing them but **that is not the problem here**.  If I understand correctly I just think **your indentation is off** and what you really want this:

```
def movie_choice():  
    user_input = raw_input("Would you like to serch your movie by IMDB ID or by\ title? ").upper()
    if user_input == "ID":
        id_choice = raw_input("Enter imdb ID: ")
        print("Serching . . .")
        return id_choice
    elif user_input == "TITLE":
        title = raw_input("Enter movie title: ")
        print("Serching . . .")
        return title
    elif user_input == "EXIT":
        sys.exit
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid choice. ")
        return movie_choice()

movie_selection = movie_choice()
print(movie_selection)
```

Note: Bear in mind that this method is still not very good because like abarnert said, not all code paths lead to a proper return value (`user_input` of EXIT just leads to exiting the program.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It'd be better to use a different variable name instead of `id_choice` for the result of `movie_choice()` to prevent confusion -- e.g. if the user enters a title instead of an IMDB ID.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying.  But I didn't want to get too deep into fixing the OP's coding style, and they specifically asked about calling `print(id_choice)`, so I just left it like that.

Comment: The advice here is good, but the terminology is misleading. You don't declare variables in Python, and `if` statements don't have a scope. More generally, this isn't about variable scope at all. The variable `id_choice` exists throughout the function as a local name. However, it isn't bound to any value (and will therefore raise an `UnboundLocalError` if you try to access it) unless you assign to it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I took your advice and used terminology more carefully.  I also just cleared up the confusion and got rid of the global `id_choice` variable.

Comment: The edit is still wrong. Outside the `if` statements is the same scope as inside the `if` statements. Only functions (and a few other things, like class definitions, and the implicit functions hidden in comprehensions) have scope in Python; statements do not. The problem here isn't that the variables are being created in the wrong scope, it's that they aren't being assigned to on every code path within that scope. (Also, I think that problem is probably at best a side note, and at worst a complete red herring, so I'm not sure it should be at the top of your answer.)

Comment: My bad, thanks for the feedback.  It should be fixed now.